# using header files in C++

Tags: c++, header-files

I have three files Date.cpp , program.cpp and Date.h as follows:

Date.h :

```
struct Date{
int mm, dd, yy;
void display();
};
```

Date.cpp

```
#include "Date.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Date::display()
{

    string m[12] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",  "Sep",  "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"

    };

    cout << m[mm-1] << ' ' << dd << ", " << yy<<endl;

}
```

program.cpp:

```
#include "Date.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main
{

    Date today = {7,1,1867};
    cout << "Today is ";
    today.display();
    return 0;
}
```

when I try to compile using:

```
g++ Date.cpp program.cpp -o Date
```

I get a whole bunch of errors complaining about program.cpp such as:

```
extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11  or -std=gnu++11{enabled by default]. 
expected '}' before 'today'. 
expected ',' or ';' before 'today'. 
'cout' does not name a type. 
'today' does not name a type. 
expected unqualified-id before 'return'. 
expected declaration before '}' token.
```

Any help to resolve these errors would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You should initialize today using a constructor.

Comment: Compile like this: `g++ -std=c++11 Data.cpp program.cpp -o Date`. Also, might I suggest having an `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, Date&)` defined instead of a `display` method? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused because you cannot use initializer list in the way you try to construct Date object, unless you compile your program with `-std=c++11` flag.

change

```
Date today = {7,1,1867};
```

to

```
Date today;
today.dd = 7;
today.mm = 1;
today.yy = 1867;
```

or provide a constructor to your Date class

```
struct Date{
Date( int m, int d, int y) : mm( m ), dd( d ), yy( y ) {}
int mm, dd, yy;
void display();
};
```

and use it as usual: `Date today(7,1,1867);`

Answer (score 1):

Compile with `-std=c++11` for `Date today = {7,1,1867};` to compile.
And you probably need `#pragma once` (or `ifndef` include guards) in your header - although this shouldn't matter in your particular case at this particular point (given you showed the entire thing).

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the object through a constructor:

```
struct Date{
  int mm, dd, yy;
  Date( int _mm, int _dd, int _yy ) : mm( _mm ), dd( _dd ), yy( _yy ) {}
  void display();
};
```

And in your main,

```
Date today( 7,1,1867 );
```

Also, as pointed out, initializer lists for arrays are supported in C++11 and so you need to set the appropriate flags for the compiler.

EDIT:

**Also, before accessing `m[mm-1]` you should check that mm is <= 12**.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors with the code you provided as well as several things you can do to improve it.

For starters fix your main:

```
int main() // put the opening and closing parenthesis after 'main'
{

    Date today = {7,1,1867};
    cout << "Today is ";
    today.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Next, ensure that your header file has the correct header guards:

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

struct Date{
    int mm, dd, yy;
    void display();
};

#endif /* DATE_H */
```

You can read more about the purpose of these header guards here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Next you need to provide a constructor to your `Date` class.

`Date( int mm, int dd, int yy);`

A lot of your issues are stylistic, but it is important that you adhere to such standards.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're trying to use aggregate initialization, but (since it contains a member function) `Date` isn't an aggregate.

C++11 adds initializer lists, which would allow you to use the same syntax, but the compiler you're using apparently requires that you explicitly enable C++11 features before it'll allow that.

I see four alternatives here. One is what the error message suggests: enable C++11 features, and have fun. The second is to add a `ctor` to your `Date` class, and use parentheses instead of braces to enclose the initialization list:

```
struct Date { 
    int mm, dd, yy;

    Date(int mm, int dd, int yy) : mm(mm), dd(dd), yy(yy) {}
};

// ...
Date today = Date(8, 1, 1867);
```

The third (and perhaps best so far) alternative under the circumstances would be to get rid of the `display` member function, and overload `operator<<` instead, so your `Date` class *will* be an aggregate, and you'll be able to use aggregate initialization like you probably intended:

```
struct Date {
    int mm, dd, yy;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Date const &d) {
    static const string m[12] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",  "Sep",  "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

    os << m[mm-1] << ' ' << dd << ", " << yy;
}
```

Then you'll be able to use normal C++ idioms to initialize and display your date object:

```
 Date d = {8, 1, 1867};

 cout << d << "\n";
```

The final alternative would be to skip defining *any* of this yourself, and use the date and time capabilities built into the standard library. `struct tm` already provides fields for day, month and year, and `strftime` (among others) supports formatting a date/time as you choose (including not only abbreviated names of months, but also localized names based on a selected locale, if you choose).